# Get IP address of ios device when connectec to wifi

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, ip-address

Can anyone suggest me the method in objective c to get IP address of iPhone device when device is connected to WiFi.

Basically I wanted to know is there any other way apart from **getifaddrs(&interfaces)** to retrieve the IP address of the device when it is connected to WiFi?

Comment: What is the reason to find an alternate solution for that? Are you facing any shortcoming in the `getifaddrs(&interfaces)` method? If so, please include that in your question.

Comment: I'm facing this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676138/ioscrash-in-64-bit-device

Comment: that's weird. I have been using the same technique to get ip address of my 64 bit devices and it works perfectly. Have you tried it on some other 64 bit device? Perhaps something wrong with that specific device.

Comment: It works fine if i move the method to appdelegate class or any other class. This was crashing when I called the method from same class where i need ip address. Guessed that could be memory issue!

Answer (score 2):

Getting information about network interfaces in Unix type systems like iOS or Mac OS X requires using some arcane C APIs. These APIs have varying amounts of visibility in [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) and [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) and [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x).

If you're exclusively targeting macOS with Objective-C, then [nshost](/questions/tagged/nshost) is your best solution. However, if you require iOS compatibility then you'll have to drop down to lower level C API such as `getifaddrs(...)` or [cfhost](/questions/tagged/cfhost).

If you want a [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) based solution even `getifaddrs(...)` comes with some bridging header requirements (making it unusable in a Framework).

Here is an example using `CFHost` and `sockaddr_in struct` that will work in Swift and on macOS and iOS (even in Frameworks). See [Host.swift](https://github.com/rjstelling/Hostess.swift) for a fully working example.

1. Use `CFHost` to get the addressing info, this will be a `CFArray` of `CFData` objets.

   ```
   let sockaddrs = CFHostGetAddressing("apple.com", &resolved)?.takeRetainedValue()
   ```
2. Get the first object

   ```
   let data = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sockaddrs, 0)
   ```
3. Cast the bytes into a `sockaddr struct`

   ```
   var storage = sockaddr_storage()
   data.getBytes(&storage, length: sizeof(sockaddr_storage))
   ```
4. Then force the `sockaddr struct` into a `sockaddr_in struct` so we can use it

   ```
   let addr = withUnsafePointer(&storage) { UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>($0).memory
   ```
5. Use the `inet_ntoa(...)` function to turn `addr.sin_addr` (IP address) into a C-string. We can then use `String(Cstring: encoding:)` to get a nice String of the IP Address.

   ```
   let address = String(CString: inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   ```

Here is a GitHub project called [Hostess.swift](https://github.com/rjstelling/Hostess.swift) that I created to solve these issues using the technique above.

Comment: Can I ask you to please [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)? You've copied and pasted this to a lot of different places.